# Cant remove padding from Card

Tags: flutter

From the project: [**GitHub**](https://github.com/InvertedX/sentinelx/blob/1eef13f6a522b3cb87b0c71d00bdf7ed629f75f6/lib/widgets/account_pager.dart#L37) I tried the followings to remove the padding:

- changing 'vertical' to 0 removes top & bottom
- changing to 'padding: EdgeInsets.zero' does nothing
- next card overlaps onto current screen
- margins I want to remove are highlight in red:

[image: Padding on Cards]

Comment: try removing the padding in _pageBuilder

Comment: @nasoj1100 lines 64 & 65? didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not the **padding** of the **Card Widget**, is the `viewport` from the **PageView**.

To "fix" this, you need to remove the `viewportFraction` property over your **PageView Controller**

Over your `initState`, go to:

```
_pageController = new PageController(initialPage: 0, keepPage: true, viewportFraction: 0.89);
```

and remove completely the property `viewportFraction: 0.89`, that's what is creating that **padding** between each **Card Widget**.